# Convergence in distribution and asymptotic distribution

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I am having a problem with proving convergence in distribution (or by law).

Consider that the sequence $X_n$ of random variables are IID and that $E[X_n]=0$ and $V[X_n]=1$.

Now define the variable $U_N$ as:

$$U_N= \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^N X_n\cdot \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{N}\right).$$

For $N\rightarrow \infty$, I want to show that $U_N$ converges by distribution, furthermore, I also want to determine the asymptotic distribution of $U_N$.

For the first part, I have tried to show convergence in probability, because this implies conv. in distribution (by law), but this was not possible since I dont have the asymptotic distribution of the $X_n$.

For the second part, I tried with the delta-method, but this did not work because of the summation of in the expression for $U_N$.

Does someone have an idea to this?

Comment: $E[U_N] = 0$.  Do you know what $Var(U_N)$ is or at least what it converges to?

Comment: Var(U_N) should be 1/N*sum(sin(n*pi)/N), which also converges to zero for N->\infty

Comment: I suspect $Var(U_N) \to \int\limits_0^1 \sin^2(\pi x)\, dx = \frac12$

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: A combination of thinking that without the $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{N})$ term the variance would be $1$ as in the central limit theorem, plus simulation and basic calculus.

Comment: Sorry, but what basic calculus, why does the integration come in? Also, how can I prove the convergence in distribution, and find the asymptotic distribution, is that then just a normal(0,1/2)

Comment: $Var(U_N)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^N Var(X_n)\cdot \frac{1}{{N}}\sin^2(\frac{n\pi}{N})$ and the sum turns into an integral in the limit

Comment: What theorem or rule is that?

Comment: $Var(aX) = a^2\, Var(X)$, and $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Answer (score 1):

One can try to check [Lindeberg's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) with $X_{N,i}:= X_i\sin\left(i\pi/N\right)$, using the following three facts:

- the limits $\lim_{N\to +\infty}N^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N\sin^2\left(n\pi/N\right)$ exists and is computable, as a limit of Riemann sums.
- $s_N=\sum_{i=1}^N\operatorname{Var}\left(X_{N,i}\right)\sim c\sqrt N$.
- $$\mathbb E\left[X_{N,i}^2\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert X_{N,i}\right\vert\gt\varepsilon s_N \right\}\right]=\mathbb E\left[X_1^2\sin^2\left(i\pi/N\right)\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert \sin\left(i\pi/N\right) X_{1}\right\vert\gt\varepsilon s_N\right\}\right]\leqslant\mathbb E\left[X_1^2\sin^2\left(i\pi/N\right)\mathbf 1\left\{\left\lvert  X_{1}\right\vert\gt\varepsilon s_N \right\}\right].$$

Comment: I see, I was not familiar with the Lindeberg condition for CLT. So if I have understood you correct, I use the Lindeberg condition on X_n,N to find that U_N will converge to a standard normal distribution for N->infinity

Comment: Yes, the limit will be a normal distribution but I have not looked whether the variance is one or not.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo - the limiting variance is $\frac12$ (it would have been $1$ without the sine term)